# Prove that $\sqrt {n − 1} +\sqrt {n + 1}$ is irrational for every integer $n ≥ 1$

Tags: real-analysis

This question is from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis.
I have a solution for it at [SOLUTION!](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch1.pdf)

The question is:

Prove that $\sqrt {n − 1} +\sqrt {n + 1}$ is irrational for every integer n ≥ 1.

And the proof I have is[image]

Now, I can't understand how to get h=$3/2$ and k=$1/2$ ?

Please help.

Comment: $2 = (n+1) - (n-1) = h^2 - k^2 = (h+k)(h-k)$.

Comment: which book writes "absurb" instead of "absurd"? (just curious)

Comment: I don't get it. If we set $n=1$ which is allowed according to the assumption $n \geq 1$ then $k=0$. Is there something wrong with what I say?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms : See the link I gave. There are many grammatical errors as the tutor whose solution I have is Chinese. But I have to focus on maths only.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do you intend to solve the system $h+k=2$ and $h-k=1$? I don't get why $h$ and $k$ become independent of $n$. And also, when the author says 'which is absurd', it means that it contradicts the fact that $h,k$ are assumed to be positive integers, he/she doesn't mean that it contradicts the fact that $h$ and $k$ must depend on $n$ since they are defined as functions of $n$?

Comment: @Sush - ah, I see: no book. Well in a tutorial I'm doing funny typos myself... so that's then no surprising thing.

Comment: It is clear that Apostol did not write that solution manual. Anyway, the route of claiming that $h=3/2$ and $k=1/2$ is a mystery. Given that one line before they were declared to be positive integers, clearly distinct, already implies that
$$2=h^2-k^2>3,$$ which is absurd.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What they do is say that $2 = h^2 - k^2 = (h + k)(h - k)$ and invoke the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. The result of that is that $h$ and $k$ are non-integers. Your approach also works. Exactly at what point the author stop and say "which is absurb" makes little difference.

Comment: Good point, Arthur. You seem to have figured out the intent of the author of that solution. All yours!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen :How you got $2=h^{2}-k^{2}>3$?

Comment: Well, I should have said $\ge3$ :-). $2^2-1^2=4-1=3$ and all the other differences of squares of positive integers are even larger. See Rebecca's answer.

Comment: Please do not include "PLEASE" in the title (nor anywhere else, actually).

Comment: Can it be done by mathematical induction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We know that $k^2$ and $h^2$ are two positive integer squares that differ by $2$.  We could just stop here, since there are no such positive integers.

If this weren't immediately apparent, let $k \geq 1$ and $i \geq 1$, then $$(k+i)^2 = k^2+2ki+i^2 \geq k^2+3.$$  So two square integers differ by $3$ or more.

Answer (score 5):

A different proof: Assume the expression is rational. Square it, to get $(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})^2=2n+2\sqrt{n^2-1}$. This is rational, so $\sqrt{n^2-1}$ is rational, so it is an integer $m$, or $n^2-1=m^2$, which means that $n=1$ and $m=0$, but if $n=1$, then the original expression is $\sqrt2$, which is irrational, and we are done.

Answer (score 4):

$(h+k)(h-k)=2$

$h+k$ and $h-k$ are integers and $h>k$

$\Rightarrow h+k=2$ and $h-k=1$

Solving, we get $h=3/2$ and $k=1/2$,  which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The following explains the mystery:-

Let start from “$n – 1 = k^2$ and $n + 1 = h^2$, where k and h are positive integer”.

Clearly, h > k and therefore we can let h = k + j for some positive integer j.

Then, $h^2 – k^2 = (n + 1) – (n – 1) = 2$

i.e. (h + k)(h – k) = 2

i.e. (2k + j)(j) = 2

This is a Diophantine type of equation saying that

“the product of two positive integers is 2, what can you say about these two numbers?”

Case 1 : (2k + j) = 1 and j = 2

--Solving them gives an unacceptable result of k = -1/2 (violating the assumption of k is positive).

Case 2 : (2k + j) = 2 and j = 1

-- Solving them gives k = 1/2

-- If k = 1/2, then h = k + j = 1/2 + 1 = 3/2

“which is (also) absurd.”